# Cannot connect to database (000webhost)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$host="mysql13.000webhost.com";      
$username="a1346032"; 
$password="<password>"; 
$db_name="a1346032_newdb"; 
$tbl_name="members"; 

mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

I have made my mysqli database in free hosting site 000webhost now i want to connect my database to my php code but every time i am getting error that    "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\hh1\checklogin.php on line 11" please help me on this and suggest if i have to add up something? thanks.

Comment: when you start localhost/phpmyadmin. than which username and password are use

Comment: most likely that remote DB service is not accessible through the firewall. Try a telnet connection to your DB on port 3306

Comment: As above, probably remote connections are not allowed with that (free, eg unreliable) host. If you are working locally (WAMP) just use your local mysql

Comment: `000webhost.com` douse not support remote mysql connection, you have to install and use your local mysql server, or upload your php code to `000webhost` server

Answer (score 10):

000webhost only lets you access the database through it's own PHP host or it's own PHPMyAdmin.

You can't access it from your own computer or another server, unless you upgrade your account (by paying).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this at that place

``` $host="localhost"; $username="a1346032"; $password="<password>"; $db_name="a1346032_newdb"; $tbl_name="members"; $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", $db_name)or die("cannot connect"); mysqli_select_db``($con, "$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); ```