# php script error i mysql connection error

Tags: php, mysql

this is my script

```
<?php
  define('HOST','databases.000webhost.com/localhost');
  define('USER','id847165_user');
  define('PASS','qwertyuiop');
  define('DB','id847165_db');
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];

    $sql = "insert into Persons (name,address) values ('$name','$address')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'success';
  }
  else{
    echo 'failure';
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is my error

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: name in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: address in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 12
failure
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 18
```

[screenshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT85l.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCiPr.jpg)

can anyone help me to make it correct

Comment: give host as 'databases.000webhost.com'

Comment: You do not do _any_ error checking or handling whatsoever, you blindly trust that the connection will work and use the handle. The connection call returns `false` (a boolean...) if it fails, that is the reason for your warnings...

Comment: @Naincy 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: name in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: address in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 12
failure
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/db.php on line 18

Comment: @Naincy sorry still facing error

Comment: @ArunMohan please see my answer

Comment: @Naincy ya i saw your answer but its worng its not working

Comment: @ArunMohan yes arun, its saying "Network not Reachable" there is nothing wrong with code there is issue on server side might be they not allowing to connect or restricted the IPs and some other security stuff....but nothing wrong with your connection code

Comment: @Naincy don't spam

Comment: you should learn about parameterized statements, because your code is wide open to **SQL Injection attacks**

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I didn't get you

Comment: @ArunMohan imagine someone posting an address like `'); DROP TABLE Persons; -- `. as soon someone does this, your Persons-table is *gone*.

Comment: this is a real simple thing. You're trying to connect to your host on a remote connection. If you didn't "pay" for their hosting, then you can't use a remote connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localhost` as connection hostname.(**Only if your file is in 000webhost server**)

change 
`'databases.000webhost.com/localhost'` to

```
'localhost'
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry still error

Comment: Is your error get reduced or not? @ArunMohan

Comment: ya its now reduced

Comment: so what are the errors now

Comment: @ArunMohan I am the first one who answer it mann. Any way thanks

Answer (score 1):

if your site is hosted on **000webhost**

```
forget your 00wh info, when you create your database, you have to give it a name, username, and password, then you'll see them in the page,
$user="";<---- User name you entered when making the database(prefixed with "a8314628_"),
$password="";<---- password you entered when making the database,
$database="a8314628_forum";<---- looks like you've got this part right,
$hostname="";<---- it will be shown where i mentioned above.,
click the MySql button, ALL the info is right there, if you've set up the db.

here's an example only:
$user="a8314628_something";
$password="password";
$database="a8314628_forum";
$hostname="mysql2.000webhost.com"
```

it looks like you put "databases.000webhost.com/localhost" somewhere, that's wrong

good luck

### :)

[image: PLease see this]

Please Follow My step to Clear your Problem,

1) open your **https://files.000webhost.com/** to upload OR add your file

2) inside public_html folder create 1 file call index.php

3) put this code inside this

```
    <?php
      define('HOST','localhost');
      define('USER','id847165_user');
      define('PASS','qwertyuiop');
      define('DB','id847165_db');
      $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $address = $_POST['address'];

        $sql = "insert into Persons (name,address) values ('$name','$address')";
      if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'success';
      }
      else{
        echo 'failure';
      }
    }else{
echo 'Please send data in $_POST First';
}
      mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

4) close&save File

5) Run your website

Comment: Hey got it? How to get your 00webhost **HOST NAME** ??

Comment: Hello sir I didn't get yoo how to take hostname

Comment: Your Hostname **databases.000webhost.com/localhost** is wrong.
Please Get it from your hosting server **000webhost** 

U can read more about it Follow thia link..

https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/i-need-help-in-connecting-my-database/6734

Comment: I can't find mysql.000 something thike that

Comment: log into your member's area, go to your account's CPanel, click on the MySql button and add a database, once that's done, it will show you the required info there.

$user="put username here";
$password="put password here";
$database="put dbname here";
$hostname="something like mysql2.000webhost.com"

mysql_connect($hostname,$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

Comment: In hostname it shows only localhost

Comment: See in the attached pic i have shown it in question

Comment: i think u can try to **hectographic-painte.000webhostapp.com**  as host name but i m not sure..

as per your sceenshot display..

Comment: No i have tried it

Comment: Pease see my updated answer..

Where is your file uploaded ??  in **000webhost**??

Comment: I didn't get you sir how to get it

Comment: in files.000webhost.com

Comment: Please see my updated answer and follow my step,

set Host name as "localhost" Problem is not there

But U put **$_POST**,  in script and Please Do it as i shown u in My answer..

Comment: Hey Dear got it or not?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function issset() in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/h5/165/847165/public_html/index.php on line 8

Comment: replace issset to **isset**

Comment: update me if it's work..

Comment: There is no output as sucess

Comment: Without domain of hosting site and just local host how it works sir

Comment: yes your problem is solved.. 

Connection error is gone.. 

u want to send data in $_POST After that it's insert data in db..

PLease REad OR Google about Form And $_POST

**I think u r new in PHP**

Comment: Run this url 

And read what is there **http://hectographic-painte.000webhostapp.com/**

Comment: If your problem is solve please up the vote :)

Comment: Ya but  now i need to connect with android devie how is it possible for that i created this script

Comment: Sir my problem is not still solved

Comment: First of all you just don't try to cheat beginners am not so fool as you ok just only one echo statement without condition so by default it will be displayed on screen

Comment: Hi @ArunMohan I think now you need to study how to call POST API from Android, Please have look in this tutorial: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64........... The answer given by Kaushik solanki is good enought.....you should accept the answer as I think.....For more android help you can ask question for android.

Comment: `issset` there's 1 `s` too much here. so edit your answer here

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code and it gives me error like

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Network is unreachable

**000webhost only lets you access the database trough it's own PHP host**

**You can't access it from your own computer, unless you upgrade your account (by paying).**
[Cannot connect to database (000webhost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610437/cannot-connect-to-database-000webhost)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$con = mysqli_connect("databases.000webhost.com","id847165_user","qwertyuiop","id847165_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else {
 echo 'connected';
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYmVDNbFkEY